# How can i build a wso2 car-application with maven?

Tags: maven, wso2, bamboo, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've build a small application with the development studio 6.3.0 and now I want to try to build the application not from the studio but with Bamboo and Maven.
Unfortunately I have no idea how I can handle this.

[image: Export .car-App in dev-Studio]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Maven plugin to create a car file without using Dev Studio. Refer the Doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Using+Maven+Package+Prepare+Plug-In